# How to set date per 'Today' click for jquery datetimepicker instance?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker, datetimepicker

I have multiple jquery datetimepickers on a page.  Trying to set the date on 'Today' button click but the following sets for all of the datetimepickers on the page?

How do I set only the one that has focus (using Trent Richarsons jquery datetimepicker)?

```
    $.datepicker._gotoToday = function (id) {
    var inst = this._getInst($(id)[0]),
    $dp = inst.dpDiv;
    this._base_gotoToday(id);
    var tp_inst = this._get(inst, 'timepicker');
    now = new Date();
    var now_utc = new Date(now.getUTCFullYear(), now.getUTCMonth(), now.getUTCDate(), now.getUTCHours(), now.getUTCMinutes(), now.getUTCSeconds());
    this._setTime(inst, now_utc);
    $('.datetime').datepicker('setDate', now_utc);  // <- this woks but sets date for all datetimepickers!  how to I set for current focus datetimepicker
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`:focus`](http://api.jquery.com/focus-selector/) pseudo-selector, like this:

```
$('.datetime:focus').datepicker('setDate', now_utc);
```

Alternatively you could also give each datepicker an specific **id** so you can select by it:

```
$('#idpicker').datepicker('setDate', now_utc);
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks!  yeah, all of my code is pretty generic so they are all contained in partial reusable views...and that code is only called once for each date time control.  Either way, thanks again!